# How to merge records from two tables using group by clause in oracle?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have two tables ward1 and ward2ie;

```
create table ward1
(
ward_id int
)

create table ward2
(
ward_id int,
ward_name varchar(10)
)
```

and the values are --

```
insert into ward1 values(101);
insert into ward1 values(101);
insert into ward1 values(102);
insert into ward1 values(102);
insert into ward1 values(102);

insert into ward2 values(101,'child');
insert into ward2 values(102,'General');
```

So I need to produce total number of occurrence of ward_id.It was simple for me i used this  code.

```
SELECT ward_id, count(ward_id) as "No of occurrence" from ward1 group by ward_id;
```

the output was --

```
ward_id   No of occurrence
101       2
102       3
```

this are the records from ward1 table, but when I want ward_name from the table ward2. I am getting error.
This is my code--

```
select ward1.ward_id as "ward_id",ward2.ward_name,
count(ward1.ward_id)as "No of occurrence" from ward1,
ward2 group by ward1.ward_id,ward2.ward_name 
having ward1.ward_id=ward2.ward_id;
```

It says not a group by expression...

I want to display like this--

```
ward_id   ward_name    No of occurrence
101       child        2
102       General      3
```

Please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close.  You really just need to join the 2 tables in a where clause (or using the preferred "join" statement)

```
select ward1.ward_id as "ward_id",ward2.ward_name,
count(ward1.ward_id)as "No of occurrence" 
from ward1,ward2 
where ward1.ward_id = ward2.ward_id
group by ward1.ward_id,ward2.ward_name;
```

Comment: Ohh yeah that was close.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the `HAVING` clause here, just use a `WHERE` clause to link your tables:

```
select ward1.ward_id as "ward_id",
       ward2.ward_name,
       count(ward1.ward_id) as "No of occurrence" 
  from ward1,
       ward2
 WHERE ward1.ward_id = ward2.ward_id
 group by ward1.ward_id,
          ward2.ward_name;
```

You should really be using the SQL-92 syntax rather than SQL-86, then you just need to add the `JOIN` condition:

```
select ward_id,
       ward2.ward_name,
       count(ward_id) as "No of occurrence" 
  from ward1
 INNER JOIN ward2 USING (ward_id)
 group by ward_id,
          ward2.ward_name;
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
select ward1.ward_id as "ward_id",
       ward2.ward_name,
       count(ward1.ward_id) as "No of occurrence"
from   ward1, ward2
where  ward1.ward_id = ward2.ward_id
group by ward1.ward_id,ward2.ward_name;
```